# Replace missing values with the value of the column with the minimum sum of differences

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have the dataframe below.

```
# Create a sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': [np.nan, 31, 29, 43, np.nan],
                   'Weight': [np.nan, 100, 60, 75, np.nan],
                   'Height': [1.65, 1.64, 1.75, 1.70, 1.68],
                   'BMI': [19, 15, 10, 25, 30]})
```

and the columns I want to replace missing values for:

`case_columns = ['Age', 'Weight']`

I want an algorithm -in python- which will replace the missing values with the same value of the row with: the minimum sum of the difference between the row of the missing value and the others.

In my example,  in row 0, the age should be 31 and the weight 100, having the min difference ((1.65-164) + (19-15)) with row 1. In row 4 the age should be 43 and the weight 75.

How can I do this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try creating a function and using df.apply()

```
def fill_missing(x):
    # if age or weight are missing
    if any(np.isnan(x.drop('Height'))):
        # create series df height - row height (exlude current row)
        height_diff = np.abs(df.drop(x.name)['Height'] - x['Height'])
        # get row index of minimum (obs: remember to use abs)
        row_idx = height_diff.idxmin()
        # substitute whatever is missing
        for feature in x.index:
            if np.isnan(x[feature]):
                x[feature] = df.loc[row_idx][feature]
    return x

df.apply(fill_missing, axis=1)

# if you want to change the value of df
df = df.apply(fill_missing, axis=1)
```

Comment: Can you make it more general? In case I have multiple rows and columns?

Comment: You can check if any value of the row is missing with any() and loop through each feature (except Height) of the X row. In this case we consider Height is never missing.

Comment: I tried but it seems that it doesn't even fill something. Could you provide a code for a more general use, please?

Comment: I edited my answer. The current code is more general, but if you want to modify the value of df, you need to do df = df.apply(fill_missing, axis=1)